# Search for text strings inside a directory and then replacing them, via ssh

Tags: command-line, ssh, text-processing

Is there any way to search for a text string e.g `Hello` and replace it with e.g `Hi` in all the text files in a directory structure with MANY sub directories? I'm running Ubuntu 17.04 x64 server.

Comment: Is this `MANY subdirectories` contains files with string "Hello" ? And you want all strings to be replaced ?

Comment: That is correct, I have about 450 000 files, in different subdirectories and I need to replace a few faulty links in them (about 8000 of them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to ssh into the remote machine and run the command described below.

The following command will replace all occurrences of "Hello" in all files inside a specific location (as per your choice) with "Hi".

```
find /path/to/main/parent/directory -type f -exec sed -i 's/hello/hi/gI' {} \;
```

#### Note

The above is case insensitive, if you want case sensitive replacement you can try with removing `I`, ie. `'s/Hello/Hi/g'`

`/path/to/main/parent/directory` : You must specify the parent directory from which your file containing string "Hello" starts.

#### for URLs

From the comment I came to know that you want to replace a URL with other which contains `://` So please use the following method to replace strings which contains URL.

```
find /path/to/main/parent/directory -type f -exec sed -i 's,/URL1/,/URL2/,gI' {} \;
```

Comment: hmm... it seem's like it's finding the text strings however it itsn't replacing them with what I want. It returns this error:                                                 
  sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Oops, there is space before the `{}`, i missed it while pasting. I have corrected the command now. Try with adding space before `{}`.

Comment: well I still get this <pre> sed: -e expression #1, char 11: unknown option to `s' </pre> maybe it is something I have to download?

Comment: No, there is nothing you need to download. I believe there may be a typo in your command. Can you paste the command you are running ?

Comment: find /var/www/html -type f -exec sed -i 's/https://twitter.com/VAMINyt/https://twitter.com/gI' {} \;

Comment: you need to escape the slashes in your search and replace terms with a backslash OR use a different separator (currently `/`) for sed that is not within your search term, e.g. `|` ==> `sed -i 's|hello|hi|gI'`

Comment: @W.Scott7182, the `sed` got confused with `//` in your twitter URL, thats why the error occurred, i have edited the answer by adding command to replace strings containing `//`

Comment: Oh! Now it's working!  Thank you very much! +rep

Answer (score 1):

Just another option using `grep -Rl` instead of find:

```
grep -Rl 'hello' /path/to/main/parent/directory | xargs -n1 sed -i 's|hello|hi|g'
```